# delete not recognized as keyword in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using wampserver, accessing MySql via phpAdmin. The queries

```
alter table employee add constraint pqr
foreign key(Super_ssn) references employee(Ssn);
```

and

```
alter table employee add constraint pqrs
foreign key(Super_ssn) references employee(Ssn)
on update cascade;
```

both work. But

```
alter table employee add constraint pqrst
foreign key(Super_ssn) references employee(Ssn)
on delete set default on update cascade;
```

gives error "#1005 - Can't create table 'company.#sql-11c4_18f' (errno: 150)".

Moreover, delete is not syntax colored as a keyword (it's black, not as same as other 'keywords' like alter, on, cascade etc).

Comment: "gives error" is not a problem description, unless you tell what "error" you're given. What is the *specific error* you're getting, including the *exact error message*?

Comment: Well, the error is - "#1005 - Can't create table 'company.#sql-11c4_18f' (errno: 150)", thanks for pointing out. But one more thing that haunts me equally is why 'DELETE' is not "recognized"?

Answer (score 2):

You **can't** use `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT` or `ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT` with InnoDB

> **[InnoDB and FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)**
>   While SET DEFAULT is allowed by the MySQL Server, **it is rejected as
>   invalid by InnoDB**. CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements using this
>   clause are not allowed for InnoDB tables.

You may try `ON DELETE SET NULL` if it fits your needs

> If ON UPDATE CASCADE or ON UPDATE SET NULL recurses to update the same
>   table it has previously updated during the cascade, it acts like
>   RESTRICT. This means that you cannot use self-referential ON UPDATE
>   CASCADE or ON UPDATE SET NULL operations. This is to prevent infinite
>   loops resulting from cascaded updates. **A self-referential ON DELETE
>   SET NULL, on the other hand, is possible, as is a self-referential ON
>   DELETE CASCADE.** Cascading operations may not be nested more than 15
>   levels deep